# Disable webview keyboard equivalents

Tags: cocoa, macos, keyboard-shortcuts, webview

I've got a webview in my window (well, several) and want to use the delete key for a custom action. Is there a way to disable the delete key shortcut in the webview so i can use it for something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do it via the webkit javascript bridge. Just check for the key in a javascript event and then call an obj-c method from there.

Comment: You might want to be specific and show some codes to your answer to give others a clearer idea. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `WebEditingDelegate` will let you know if a command is about to performed, and so you could override that perhaps.

Comment: As far as i can see, the WebEditingDelegate is used for the DOM editing mode of webkit. I don't think it's got anything to do with keyboard shortcuts